# What is this fast growing plant/bush in garden?

Tags: identification, shrubs

On fall of 2021, this plant just sprouted up, and survived the frost. I currently live in Charlotte, NC, USA. It is about 5 feet after growing for 1 year. I also seen it around in other places as I was going, so more likely to be a weed. This plant doesn't produce flowers (until about October) or berries. I tried to search the image on the internet but the results were a nightshade plant but I know it isn't a nightshade plant because their leaves are different from the one's in this image.

[image: Plant or Bush in garden]

Closer picture of leaves: [image: Closer Picture of leaves]

Another close picture of leaves: [image: Another Close picture of leaves]

Flowers (came about October): [image: picture with flowers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Baccharis halimifolia — eastern false willow](https://gobotany.nativeplanttrust.org/species/baccharis/halimifolia/) is common (weed) in south eastern US.

From the linked site especially compare to [this](https://newfs.s3.amazonaws.com/taxon-images-1000s1000/Asteraceae/baccharis-halimifolia-le-azinovjev.jpg) photo.

https://identify.plantnet.org/ says 10%. If you are not sure it is this species, we need more  details.